# python serial.tools.list_ports only showing bluetooth ports on mac

Tags: python, macos, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to communicate with some dc servo controllers i have in my lab. to do this, i need to send byte strings over a USB serial port. I am trying to build a small python package to do this for me so that I can build some higher level routines in python without having to reference the byte strings all the time. First, i am just trying to communicate with the device over USB in the python interactive interpreter in the Mac terminal. I am using pyserial, and specifically, I am trying to see all the ports on my computer by using `serial.tools.list_ports`. Whenever I do this, all I get is a list of bluetooth ports, and none of the other ports, USB or otherwise.

```
python -m serial.tools.list_ports
/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
/dev/cu.Model12-CSRGAIA
/dev/cu.SANGEANWR-22-SPPDev
/dev/cu.SANGEANWR-22-WirelessiAP
/dev/cu.WH-1000XM4-Airoha_APP
/dev/cu.WH-1000XM4-GSOUND_BT_AU
/dev/cu.WH-1000XM4-GSOUND_BT_CO
/dev/cu.WH-1000XM4-IAPSERVER
/dev/cu.WH-1000XM4-SerialHPC
/dev/cu.WH-1000XM4-SerialMC
10 ports found
```

These are just bluetooth devices my computer has connected to in the past.

I've tested this with devices connected and disconnected over USB and they still aren't visible. I did try this on the Linux machine in our lab and I could see the USB ports (and all the others) listed like `/dev/ttyUSB0/`. Is there something mac specific that I need to enable, or is there something else going on here?

Comment: Sorry if this is a new or very routine question. I am new to python and any kind of development in general.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you post some of your code to show what you did?

Comment: @VirtualScooter I have not done anything so far besides type python3 -m serial.tools.list_ports into the command line and read the output. There isn't much code to see yet.

Comment: same here on Mac OSX Monterey: (base) welcome: python-embedded % uname -a
Darwin local 21.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.5.0: Tue Apr 26 21:08:22 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.121.3~4/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
(base) welcome@Traianos-MacBook-Pro python-embedded % python3 -m serial.tools.list_ports
/dev/cu.BLTH        
/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
2 ports found`